# What's the right way to save instance state only on rotation?

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-rotation, savestate

I understand that when a device rotates, Android destroys and recreates the current activity in order to load orientation-specific resources. To save state, I can use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`and the regular `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` but this saves and restores state each time the app is destroyed/created for any reason.

What I want to do is to save/restor state **only** when the app was destroyed/created because of an orientation change; when the app is destroyed because of memory or the user kills it, I'm not interested in saving state. ¿How can I do this?

Comment: You only save member variables, data or dynamic content. Anything with an ID android automatically takes care of saving for you.

There are callbacks (`onLowMemory`) that allow you to be informed of low memory within the Activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my question was wrong from the beginning.

When the device rotates, Android calls `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` as a way for the developer to save/restore state. When the activity is destroyed via back button or `finish()`, `onSaveInstanceState` is **not** called and the `savedInstanceState` bundle that's passed to `onCreate()` is null. So trying to answer the "was this created after a rotation or not?" question is irrelevant.

Posted in case someone has the same question and thanks to all that took time to read and help.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `onConfigurationChange()` method. To do that you need to override it in your Activity's code and set a few parameters in your Manifest:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

You have to add these attributes (`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`) to your activity, set as many as you want to handle:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Be careful, with this setup, your activity will not restart, as mentioned in the docs, so, if you want to restart it you will need to implement a manual restart.

> Now, when one of these configurations change, MyActivity does not
>   restart. Instead, the MyActivity receives a call to
>   onConfigurationChanged().

Link to the [main documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).